# Yii2-configure swiftmailer to send emails using gmail smtp

Tags: php, email, yii2, xampp, gmail

I am working on `yii2`. Using my `localhost` on `XAMP` I am trying to send an email. While sending the email I am getting the bellow error in `POSTMAN`.

> "name": "Exception",
>       "message": "Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]",
>       "code": 0,
>       "type": "Swift_TransportException",

Bellow is my `common/config/main-local`

```
   'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport'=>[
            'class'=>'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username'=>'MY GMAIL ID',
            'password'=>'Password',
            'port'=>'465', //587 also tried this with ssl and tls
            'encryption'=>'ssl' //tls also tried with port 465,26 and 587
        ],
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        //'useFileTransport' => false,
    ],
```

Below is my sending request

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('MY ID')
        ->setTo('SEND ID')
        ->setSubject('New Message')
        ->setTextBody('HI')
        ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
        ->send();
```

I have searched each and every question(s) but couldn't able to solve the issue. What should I do now ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) for your account first.

Then you should use the following settings for `port:587` and `encryption:tls` and it will work, I use these setting for my local computer at home to send emails from localhost.

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport'=>[
            'class'=>'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username'=>'MY GMAIL ID',
            'password'=>'Password',
            'port' => '587' ,
            'encryption' => 'tls' ,
        ],
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        //'useFileTransport' => false,
    ],
```

Comment: Yes it works with slight modification in code.... 

`streamOptions' => [ 'ssl' =>
                    [ 'allow_self_signed' => true,
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    ],
                ]`

Comment: Where did you put this piece of code ? I also enabled less secure apps but this didn't help at all.

Comment: @TomaTomov this goes in you config

Comment: Thank you! Think I found it :)

Comment: @TomaTomov you are welcome , dnt forget to upvote if it helped ,

Answer (score 0):

The comment of Muhammad is helpful. I don't have enough reputation to add this comment to his post.

After enabling access to less secure apps on gmail, WAIT for some time for the change to take effect, otherwise, you will continue to get errors about 'TLS not available' as it happened to me.

To put everything together,

```
 'mailer' => [
     'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
     'transport' => [
         'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
         'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
         'username' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
         'password' => 'your password',
         'port' => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls', 
        'streamOptions' => [ 'ssl' => [ 'allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, ], ]

     ],
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

*** IMPORTANT ***
Disabling SSL verification has security implications. Without verification of the authenticity of SSL/HTTPS connections, a malicious attacker can impersonate a trusted endpoint (such as GitHub or some other remote Git host), and you'll be vulnerable to a Man-in-the-Middle Attack. Be sure you fully understand the security issues before using this as a solution.

1. Make sure you have enabled [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) for your account first
2. Check Gmail through [other email platforms](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229)
3. Edit \common\config\main-local.php

   ```
   'mailer' => [
       'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
       'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
       'useFileTransport' => false,
       'transport' => [
           'class'      => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
           'host'       => 'smtp.gmail.com',
           'username'   => 'yourname@gmail.com',
           'password'   => 'yourpass',
           'port'       => '587',
           'encryption' => 'tls',
           'streamOptions' => [
               'ssl' => [
               'allow_self_signed' => true,
               'verify_peer' => false,
               'verify_peer_name' => false,
               ],
           ],
       ],
   ],
   ```

Comment: There is no need for adding 'streamOptions' object